# Output in special format

Tags: sql-server

May any one please help me how to code the below scenerio in sql.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
Year VARCHAR (50),
Month VARCHAR (50),
GROUPS VARCHAR (50),
SALESPERNO VARCHAR (50),
Net VARCHAR (50)

)

INSERT @T

SELECT '2014','1','A','6607','109.34' UNION ALL
SELECT '2014','2','A','6607','13.42' UNION ALL
SELECT '2014','3','A', '6607','359.41' UNION ALL
SELECT '2014','1','A', '6608','99.52' UNION ALL
SELECT '2014','2','A','6608','95.62' UNION ALL
SELECT '2014','3','A', '6608','89.63' UNION ALL
SELECT '2014','1','B','8888','340.95' UNION ALL
SELECT '2014','2','B','8888','652.25' UNION ALL
SELECT '2014','3','B','8888','352.26' 

SELECT * FROM @T
```

Here: month 1 = Jan, 2=feb, 3=mar

Output is sum of net for a particular `salesperno` and groups for jan feb mar and total like this:

```
January|    February |  March|  QFY   | SALES_GROUP |SALESPERSON_NUMBER    
109.34 |    13.42   |  359.41|  482.17|  A          | 6607
99.52  |    95.62   |  89.63 |  284.77|  A          | 6608    
340.95 |    652.25  |  352.26|  1345.46| B          | 8888
```

Comment: google and learn about the CASE statement in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in multiple ways. As Tab Alleman suggested one way is with the help of [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) and [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx).

```
select
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Month]=1 THEN [NET] END) [January],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Month]=2 THEN [NET] END) [February],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Month]=3 THEN [NET] END) [March],
    SUM([NET]) [QFY],
    [GROUPS] [SALES_GROUP],
    [SALESPERNO] [SALESPERSON_NUMBER]
from @T
group by
    [GROUPS],
    [SALESPERNO]
```

This is another way, with [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
SELECT
    [1] [January],
    [2] [February],
    [3] [March],
    [1]+[2]+[3] [QFY],
    [GROUPS] [SALES_GROUP],
    [SALESPERNO] [SALESPERSON_NUMBER]
FROM @T
PIVOT (
    SUM(NET)
    FOR [Month] in ([1],[2],[3])
) pvt
```